# Application Install Unsuccessful-while installing app viaOTA

Tags: android

I have developed an application using Android SDK 1.5, application works well on Android Simulator.
Now, I am trying to install application on actual device. I don't have the Android device. So, I am going by OTA way.

For this, I have generated the self sign keystore using keytool utility.
And, using Eclipse's "Eclipse Signed Application package.." option I have generated the signed .apk file and moved it to my web server.
Also, i added MIME type on web server for .apk.

But, when I am trying to download and install the same application on device, application get downloaded and it also prompts for permission. After thag when I click on "Install", it fails with error Application Install Unsuccefull.

Interestingly, I test this url on simulator browser, and it worked perfectly well and application get installed successfully.

Even, I checked that, SDCard is there on device. Settings -> Applications and "Unknown sources" option is alos checked.

Am I clear to you all?
Any Idea what may be going wrong here?

Thanks and appreciate your response,
S.Satheesh

Comment: I'm not familiar with OTA update, but for this kind of usage I simply send the apk file by mail and open it on the device with APKatcher (see http://www.androidtapp.com/apkatcher/).

Answer (score 2):

What happens if connect the phone via a USB cable and [install the application using the `adb install` command](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#move)?  Testing this will allow you to determine if the problem is with the package or the over the air update.

Also, you could try running [`adb logcat` to view the logs from your phone](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#logcat) after the failed install as this should show you what the problem is.

Comment: Indeed. Running `adb install` should give you a specific error message straight away when you try to install the APK.